# Get product custom fields ACF in post page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get a product custom field `( ACF )` based on `product ID` in a post page.

I tried things like this `$price[] = get_sub_field('price', $productId);` but it doesn't seems to work when taking something else than the `post id`.

I managed to get the title though by doing like this `<?php echo $product->get_title(); ?>` but not sure on how to go to get the custom fields.

Comment: is the `price` custom field?

Comment: @GufranHasan Yes it is. But not specific to price as i am trying to get other custom fields =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know `$product->ID` will not work anyway. `So I think now your problem is how to get the product ID`.

=> In Archive pages like `shop or in Single product` pages:
  Using `get_the_id()` will give you mostly always the product id (the post ID).

```
$price= get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'price', true );
```

[reference link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80081/display-custom-field-value-on-woocommerce-product-page)

You can also use `global $product;` with `$product->get_id()`

```
global $product;
$price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'price', true );
```

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know how i would be able to get a field from a repeater by doing this way though ?

Comment: Yes. For example i got multiple trims by car ( This is a repeater ). And each trim got a field {transmission}, and i'd like to get all the transmission value for each trims. Still on a post page

Comment: I think this `get_post_meta( product_id, custom_field_name, true );` line will work in this situation

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a solution. Have a nice day =)